# Is there a way to see how many accounts does a public key own?

Tags: accounts, public-key

Lets say I own a handful of accounts. Is there a way to see how many accounts I own by doing a public key lookup? And where can one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cleos get accounts`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-accounts)

> Retrieves all accounts associated with a defined public key.
>
> **Positionals**
>
> `public_key TEXT` - The public key to retrieve accounts for
>
> **Example**

```
$ cleos get accounts EOS8mUftJXepGzdQ2TaCduNuSPAfXJHf22uex4u41ab1EVv9EAhWt
 {
   "account_names": [
      "testaccount"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: This ^ and most block explorers like EOSFlare will allow just putting in a public key in the search box which resolves those relevant accounts.